# Getting UnicodeEncodeError when writing to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I am using python 3.6 and trying to fetch the youtube video comments and create a `csv` file of it. From `json` file, I get from the google server I try to fetch some object but while writing it to `csv` it shows an `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
for i in range(0,length):
    results= result["items"][i].get('snippet').get("topLevelComment").get('snippet').get("textDisplay")
    print(results)
    results=results.replace(",","")

    csvFile.write(results)
    csvFile.write('\n')
    time.sleep(STAGGER_TIME)

csvFile.close()
```

This is the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-23: character maps to <undefined>
```

Converting results using `encode(utf-8)` did not help because after that it will give

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

before executing your code.

Then convert the response using str(results). Not sure what line you are getting the TypeError on after setting default encoding to utf-8.

Comment: at  results=results.replace(",", "") i am getting the type error

Comment: i am using python 3 and by default it is UTF-8

Comment: Can you convert the response to str i.e. str(results)?

Comment: did not helped str(results)

Comment: Okay can you show the code that is actually retrieving the results data? Cannot debug further without trying myself.